# How to add your own icon in pyinstaller when opened the file

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

When I was compiling my python file to exe via pyinstaller. I was thinking is there any way to add your own custom icon when opened the file.

Like when I open my file I see this:

[The circled one is my Tkinter app icon on taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BSxs.png)

[The circled one is the Tkinter logo when I open my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC8qc.png)

So how to fix this. I want to add my own logo

Answer (score 1):

In your app's code, add this:

```
root.iconbitmap("path_to_icon.ico")
```

Where `root` is the variable assigned to `Tk()` and `path_to_icon.ico` is the path where the icon is stored.

.

When using pyinstaller, add the flag `--icon="path_to_icon.ico"`

Example:
`pyinstaller my_program.py --icon="icon.ico"`